# How could I create a table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xml-parsing

I have XML like this:

```
<root>
    <object a1="0" b1="2" c1="12/01" a2="0" b2="2" c2="12/03" a3="0" b3="2" c3="12/06"/>
    <object a1="0" b1="2" c1="12/01" a2="0" b2="2" c2="12/03" />
    <object />
</root>
```

I need to create tables for each object.

like for `object[0]`:

```
----------------------------
a1 value | b1 value | c1 value|
----------------------------
a2 value | b2 value | c2 value|
----------------------------
a3 value | b3 value | c3 value|
----------------------------
```

and for `object[1]`:

```
----------------------------
a1 value | b1 value | c1 value|
----------------------------
a2 value | b2 value | c2 value|
----------------------------
```

But I don't know how to use XSLT to do this loop since each attribute has different name.
Could you help me or show me a way to solve this?
Should I use JavaScript to parse the attributes?

expected HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>a1 value</td>
  <td>b1 value</td>
  <td>c1 value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a2 value</td>
  <td>b2 value</td>
  <td>c2 value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a3 value</td>
  <td>b3 value</td>
  <td>c3 value</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The number of rows are depend on the number of attributes in object.

Comment: Can you post the expected output HTML code?

Comment: do attributes all have same naming protocol as shown? ie letter and incremental row number

Comment: "*The number of rows are depend on the number of attributes in object.*" How exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using jQuery

```js
var attrs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var html = '';
$(xml).find('object').each(function (i) {
    var ctr = 1,
        $obj = $(this);
     html += '<h3>Table #' + (i + 1) + '</h3><table>';

    do {
        html += '<tr>';
        $.each(attrs, function (_, letter) {                
            html += '<td>' + $obj.attr(letter + ctr) + '</td>';               
        });
        ctr =  $obj.attr('a' + (ctr + 1)) !== undefined ? ctr +1 : -1;           
        html += '</tr>';
    } while (ctr > 0);
    html += '</table>';
});

$('body').append(html)
```

It makes the assumption that if the first attribute `a` has a value for a row, that all other attributes would also exist for that row

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/awbqs93a/2/)**</kbd>